# LuaJit won't find a library "lua-vips" installed via "luarocks"

Tags: lua, luajit, luarocks

I have this lua file:

```
-- test1.lua 


--require "luarocks.loader"
vips = require "vips"
--vips = require "lua-vips"



local img = vips.Image.new_from_file("img1.jpg")
-- [...................]
```

It won't find the library "lua-vips" installed via "luarocks":

```
$ luajit test1.lua 
luajit: error loading module 'vips' from file '/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.3/':
  cannot read /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.3/: Is a directory
stack traceback:
  [C]: at 0x0102caa660
  [C]: in function 'require'
  test1.lua:2: in main chunk
  [C]: at 0x0102c3b8a0
```

Even after I add

`export LUA_PATH="/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.3/"`

to `~/.profile`, it won't.

The content of the directory `luarocks` -- `lua-vips` exists:

```
  ls /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.3/

  lua-vips  manifest
```

How how to fix this?

```
$ luarocks path
export LUA_PATH='/Users/my_user/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/Users/my_user/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/local/Cellar/luarocks/3.0.1/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua'
export LUA_CPATH='/Users/my_user/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so'
export PATH='/Users/my_user/.luarocks/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/my_user/.yarn/bin:/Users/my_user/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/Users/my_user/.nix-profile/bin:/Users/my_user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin:/Users/my_user/.cargo/bin:/Users/my_user/.gem/ruby/2.5.1/bin:/Users/my_user/.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin:/Users/my_user/.rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/my_user/go/bin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that LUA_PATH doesn't work the same way PATHs usually work.

You don't give it a directory, but a template string with an `?` representing the name of the library to load.

So, for example, if you want to find files in the `/path/to/libs/` directory, you'd write `"/path/to/libs/?.lua;/path/to/libs/?/init.lua"` for the path.

If you literally add `"/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.3/"`, Lua will try to load that directory as a Lua file, which causes your error.

Remove that environment variable and tell us what error you get.

Also keep in mind that adding something to `.profile` requires logging out and back in again for the changes to take effect (or to `source ~/.profile` in every new shell you open)